# How does the rdp file signature creation work?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, remote-desktop, rdp

How is the rdp file signature created (I mean the rdpsign.exe internal algorithm ) ?
Which encryption technology is involved?

rdpsign.exe adds two new values to the rdp file: "signscope:s:" and "signature:s:".
The signscope is probably the set of secure settings considered worth to be added to the data blob that the signature is made of.
The signature value is base64 encoded.
I can successfully decode it but don't recognize the resulting binary data.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753982(v=ws.10).aspx for a description of the rdpsign.exe command.

I've not found any specifications online.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately it's not really a programming question. Whereever it is asked you could at least show the resulting signature format and possibly the certificate containing the public key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer (rdpsign.exe reverse engineered):

https://github.com/nfedera/rdpsign